# integral with vectoric varying coeficient

Tags: matlab, filter-design, sampling, integration, waveform-similarity

i have a basic function exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2 which i integrate in a certain interval.
i want to multiply my basic function with a vectoric coefficient called coef_vec that varies with the interval.
so if the integral is at 5 my basic function whould be multiplied with coef_vec(5).
i know that its som how turning the integral into a loop.
Is it possible in matlab?
Thanks.

```
coef_vec=linspace(1,10,100)
fun = @(x)coef_vec*exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;
q = integral(fun,1,10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a closed-form expression for the weighting function, you can use it  directly. Here, the weight is linear, so you can replace `coef_vec` by `x`and be ok.

```
fun = @(x)x.*exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;
q = integral(fun,1,10);
```

If not, an option is to define `coef_vec` on a larger interval, interpolate it with a suitable closed-form interpolating function, and use this under the integral.

Or, simply, evaluate the integral with a function like `trapz`. Here is a comparison, with close results

```
coef_vec=linspace(1,10,100);
fun0 = @(x)exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;
fun1 = @(x)x.*exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;
q1 = integral(fun1,1,10);

q2 = trapz(coef_vec,coef_vec.*fun0(coef_vec));
disp([q1 q2])

>>    0.0245    0.0245
```